# What criteria do I need to match for a replacement power supply for my PC?

Tags: power-supply, dell-inspiron

My personal troubleshooting and a second opinion have concluded that the power supply on my Dell Inspiron 660 Desktop is no longer working and must be replaced.

Trouble is, I don't know how to go about looking for the right replacement.  I tried searching on Amazon but wasn't able to find anything that looks the same as the power supply in my desktop.

I was told that getting a different power supply than the exact one in my computer is fine *as long as I get one with equal or greater maximum power output*. As best as I can tell, the maximum power output on my power supply is 300 W.

- Is the above statement correct, that I don't need the exact same power supply but do need one with the correct maximum power output?
- If not, what criteria do I need to match on a replacement unit?

[image]

Comment: You can't go just by power.  The form factor and connector complement need to match, and the power available at each of the various voltages needs to be similar or greater.  The Dell OEM replacement will probably be a lot more expensive than a third party unit.  This was made by Liteon, and you may find one under the Liteon brand that is an exact match and probably cheaper.  Otherwise, look for units advertised as a direct replacement for the model number (and verify the details).  It's fine to get a direct replacement that has a higher wattage rating, it will provide more capacity if needed.

Comment: So you need help **`Finding right power supply for my Dell desktop`** So why not just go to Dell.com and from there and the... **Contact Us: [Click to Chat](http://channels.us.dell.com/netagent/cimlogin.aspx?questid=ECD0842F-ABAB-4AB0-858A-95EAB5ED8593&portid=9C39C2B5-F1B5-4B42-9928-10AE367360BB) or Call 1-877-717-3355** and figure out your options based on what Dell says?